# How to put a window opened with window.open() behind the opener window?

Tags: javascript, onclick, href

I have a link that when clicked replaces the current page with another through the default `<a>` element click behaviour, but which also calls a JavaScript function to open another page in a new window. I would like the new window opened from my JavaScript function to appear behind the current window but can't figure out how to do this. In actual usage, I am feeding click thrus to a database, the link that is controlled by the window.open statement. The other link is to the clients site in a new window. I want the clients site to appear on top.

My current code is as follows:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    function countClicks(a,b)
    { 
       window.open("http://stackoverflow.com?id="+a+"&id2="+b, "_blank");
    }
</script>

<a href="google.com" name="xy" onclick="javascript:countClicks(2,3);">test</a>
```

So for the example URLs shown above I would like the (original) window with Google to appear in front of the new window with StackOverflow, but the new window always opens in front.

Comment: Are you asking how to set the position and size of the newly opened window so that it will appear over the link that was clicked to open it?

Comment: I am looking to have, in the example above, the google window appear above stackoverflow window. Right now it appears behind.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I've (radically) reworded your question to reflect what you've said in your comment. Essentially you're asking how to create a "pop under" (as compared to a "pop up"). Unrelated to your question, note that in an inline event attribute like `onclick="something"` you don't need to say `javascript:` - it is assumed.

Comment: If I read that right, he's trying to implement pop-**under** behavior, which is usually reserved for "evil" purposes. Also, it Just Won't Work for many people who have their popup blockers and/or javascript permissions set up "correctly" in their browser. Pop-unders simply won't work in my browser, for example.

Comment: In actual usage, I am feeding click thrus to a database, the link that is controlled by the window.open statement. The other link is to the clients site in a new window. I want the clients site to appear on top. Not sure where your evil statement applies in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Popup behavior varies based on browser/user settings. I haven't been able to replicate the *open behind* behaviour myself, but I believe what you're looking for is `.focus()`.

Try:

```
window.open("http://stackoverflow.com?id="+a+"&id2="+b, "_blank").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`window.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.focus) at the end of your existing function:

```
function countClicks(a,b) {
   window.open("http://stackoverflow.com?id="+a+"&id2="+b, "_blank");
   window.focus();
}
```

That should bring the existing window back to the front, noting that behaviour may vary between browsers and depending on popup-blocking settings, etc.

Or you could just swap the two urls, i.e., put the StackOverflow url in the `href` with the appropriate query string specified directly rather than in JS, and put the Google url in the `window.open()` call.

Comment: unfortunately, that does not work. In actual usage, I am feeding click thrus to a database, the link that is controlled by the window.open statement. The other link is to the clients site in a new window. The clients site to appear on top.

Comment: (Assuming you get it working) Isn't that going to annoy users because they may not notice the new window is there until they close the "main" window and then they'll be left wondering where the other one came from.

Comment: the window that feeds the database the count codes never shows, what they see is the original page reloading and the link to the ad client open up in a new tab or window